# Strange CSS Appearing In Safari But Not Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I've just switched over a database for a front end website and some strange CSS is appearing under just one image, but I cannot find the CSS in the code, in fact i'm pretty sure it's not there.

This is looking at the code in browser using google chrome:

[image]
As you can see no CSS.

But in Safari:

[image]

Lots of CSS is added on the end of just this one image. The images are pulled from a database and displayed on screen, this was working before i switched the database over, and I can't seem to find it in the code:

[image]

As you can see it's not being added inline when it's echoed onto the page

My question is ... what could be causing this inline CSS to be added to this one image and is there anyway to find out where it came from?

Comment: css specific for safair

Comment: How do I get it to you know .. go away? It's making my image disappear, it's odd that it would only be applied to one image - in a loop i display 3 on this page.

Comment: I'll bet it's from a Safari extension. Do you see it in an uncustomized account?

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not a tiny image.

Answer (score 0):

If it safari on mac with retina display, some of the libraries can add styles to the image

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the plugin ad blocker was blocking my image.